# Most efficient to read file into separate variables using fstream

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, fstream

I have tons of files which look a little like:

```
12-3-125-BINARYDATA
```

What would be the most efficient way to save the `12`, `3` and `125` as separate integer variables, and the `BINARYDATA` as a `char-vector`?

I'd really like to use `fstream`, but I don't exactly know how to (got it working with `std::strings`, but the `BINARYDATA` part was all messed up).

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient" in this context ?

Comment: I mean, iterators didn't seem very efficient to me, maybe there's a less time consuming way to do it.

Comment: @Oliver - Bet the iterators are way faster than the disk, so how would you notice?

Comment: Are the records fixed length?

Comment: Is the BINARYDATA fixed length?

Comment: How does one determine the end of a record?

Comment: Define efficient: (Speed of retrieval) (Size of storage) (ease of writing/reading code)

Comment: @Thomas Matthews - No, the length of the BINARYDATA differs from file to file. The end of a record is EOF I guess.
@Martin - Ease of writing/reading code. How would the size of storage matter? I want to read the files and work with the values (12, 3, 125 and BINARYDATA) after. ^^

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient method for reading data is to read many "chunks", or records into memory using the fewest I/O function calls, then parsing the data in memory.

For example, reading 5 records with one `fread` call is more efficient than 5 calls to `fread` to read in a record.  Accessing memory is always faster than accessing external data such as files.

Some platforms have the ability to memory-map a file.  This may be more efficient than reading the using I/O functions.  Profiling will determine the most efficient.

Fixed length records are always more efficient than variable length records.  Variable length records involve either reading until a fixed size is read or reading until a terminal (sentinel) value is found.  For example, a text line is a variable record and must be read one byte at a time until the terminating End-Of-Line marker is found.  Buffering may help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by Binary Data? Is it a 010101000 char by char or "real" binary data? If they are real "binary data", just read the file as binary file. First read 2 bytes for the first int, next 1 bytes for -, 2 bytes for 3,and so on, until you read the first pos of binary data, just get file length and read all of it.

Comment: BINARYDATA is real binary data. 12-3-125 are just the first three numbers that came to my mind, they're VERY random (from 0 to 1,000,000,000,000 !).

Comment: Even it is random, but when we write it to file, it has a type, right? So it takes 2 or 4 bytes or more, depend on its type.

Comment: But when I just read fixed 4 bytes each file to get the first integer value, wouldn't it be possibly exceeding limits (4 Byte: 2.147.483.647 < 1.000.000.000.000)?